# Uncaught TypeError: reportValidity[] is not a function

Tags: javascript, forms, typeerror, checkvalidity

I am working on a form on which on hitting save button after entering the necessary details in it, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.reportValidity[s] is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> 
    at f  (Line#57)
    at HTMLDivElement.f.handle
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch
```

```
const legalityMethod = function () { 
return 'reportValidity' in document.createElement('input') ? 'reportValidity' : 'checkValidity'; 
}();
```

Line#57 corresponds to the following while loop;

```
function validate(form, field) {

    while (m && m--) {

        switch (fields[m]) {

            case 'hello_world':

                form.hello_world.setCustomValidity(config.language['amazing_world']);
                break;
        }
    }

    return form.reportValidity[legalityMethod]();  //line#57
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what are the reasons behind this error and how I can get rid of this error.

Comment: I believe it should be `form[legalityMethod]();`

Comment: @dotconnor like this  `return form[legalityMethod]();`

Comment: yes, previously you tried calling `form.reportValidity.reportValidity()`

Comment: Nope, I didn't try calling that previously.

Comment: Well, your legalityMethod is just a self-executing method that will always return `reportValidity` unless you're in IE, so the variable legalityMethod is `reportValidity`, then in line #47 you try to call a `reportValidity` method on the actual `reportValidity` method for the given form but there is no such method on the method you should be called.

Comment: @dotconnor Ok, Instead of this line `return form.reportValidity[legalityMethod]();` it should be `return form[legalityMethod]();`   ?

Comment: Yes @flash that should work